Concatenate two previous loglines in multicodec in logstash
2022-03-01 12:00:00 INFO Loading application...
2022-03-01 12:00:00 INFO Starting application...
  2022-03-01 12:00:01 INFO Loading configuration...
  2022-03-01 12:00:01 INFO Loading configuration2...
2022-03-01 12:00:01 INFO New configuration...

Can we have the first 4 lines as a single multiline in logstash.
input {
    file {
        path => "/*.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^(\s)"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}


helps in giving line 2-4 as a multiline but i want line 1-4 as the multiline
Tried different patterns for the same but its not working
